# android app problem on Macbook

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I have developed an android application which is working fine on win7 PC. But when i copied this same app to macbook and then i got following errors.

```
[2011-07-11 17:49:38 - MyApplication] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE
[2011-07-11 17:49:38 - MyApplication] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-07-11 17:49:39 - MyApplication] Launch canceled!
```

Emulator also doesn't work here.

I read posts which contains exactly same problems but these doesn't helped me.

Comment: yes, i tried HelloWorld program and it's perfectly working with emulator.. 

I also did changing in manifest file but no success, 

i.e. 
<uses-library android:name="ling.ling"
            android:required="true"/>

"ling.ling" is package name...

Comment: Do you have free space on your emulator? Try `$ adb shell df`

Answer (score 0):

this had happened to me before, the problem is with the Auto-generated R.java, apparently Eclipse for OS X changes some syntax around on that specific file..

my recommendation:

rebuild your package in osX eclipse so it auto-generates your R file.